# Reduce a date range to an array of the last days of each month?

Tags: ruby, arrays, date-range

I have a Ruby date range: `range = Date.parse("February 1, 2013")..Date.parse("January 15, 2014")`

If you do `range.to_a` and convert it to an array, you get array items of every single day in that range.

What I want is an array of the last day of each month.

Basically something like: `[2013-02-28, 2013-03-31, 2013-04-30, ..., 2013-12-31, 2014-01-31]`

Comment: you want 2014-01-31 in the result, even though your date range only goes up through "January 15, 2014"?

Comment: That's sort the "edge" of it, but basically want to get each month that's in the range and then spit out array of the last day of each of those months.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way, off the top of my head:

```
range = Date.parse("February 1, 2013")..Date.parse("January 15, 2014")
range.to_a.map {|date| Date.new(date.year,date.month,1)}.uniq.map {|date| date.next_month.prev_day}
```

Or in other words:

For every date in the array

1. Make the day element equal to 1 to find the first of each month ...
2. Make the set unique, so you have one element per month ...
3. Add one month to each value ...
4. Subtract one day.

Answer (score 1):

A negative day-of-month counts backwards, so -1 is the last day of the month:

```
require 'date'

def last_days_of_months(year=Date.today.year)
  (1..12).map{|month| Date.new(year, month, -1)}
end

puts last_days_of_months
```

Output:

```
2014-01-31
2014-02-28
2014-03-31
2014-04-30
2014-05-31
2014-06-30
2014-07-31
2014-08-31
2014-09-30
2014-10-31
2014-11-30
2014-12-31
```

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'date'
COMMON_YEAR_DAYS_IN_MONTH = [nil, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]

def days_in_month(month, year = Time.now.year)
   return 29 if month == 2 && Date.gregorian_leap?(year)
   COMMON_YEAR_DAYS_IN_MONTH[month]
end

range = Date.parse("February 1, 2013")..Date.parse("January 15, 2014")
last_year = range.last.year
last_month = range.last.month
last_day =  Time.new(last_year, last_month, days_in_month(last_month, last_year)).to_date

range.select { |d| d.day == days_in_month(d.month, d.year) }.push(last_day).map(&:to_s)
 # => ["2013-02-28", "2013-03-31", "2013-04-30", "2013-05-31", "2013-06-30", "2013-07-31", "2013-08-31", "2013-09-30", "2013-10-31", "2013-11-30", "2013-12-31", "2014-01-31"]
```

Comment: What is the data in `COMMON_YEAR_DAYS_IN_MONTH`?

Comment: @Shpigford Number of days in each months of the Year

Comment: So why is there a `nil` value in there?

Comment: @Shpigford month starts counting from 1 and not 0 so we put a nil to index the months correctly

Comment: Just realized, this gets really close to what I need, but in my example case, I need it to include the last day of partial months. If you look at my example, the last item in the array is `2014-01-31`. So in the case of a partial month, I still want the last day of that month.